# Basic Differential Geometry Problem 3

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

This problem is part of a practice problem set for my exam, and I'm having trouble with it.

Let $F_1,F_2,F_3 : \mathbb{C} → \mathbb{C}$ be functions given by the formulas $F_1(z) =\frac{z-1}{z+1}, \ F_2(z) = z^2, \ F_3(z)=\frac{1+z}{1−z}$, and
$\omega = \{z ∈ C \ \vert \ |z| = 1\}$ be the unit circle.

(a) Draw the lines $\omega_1 = F_1(\omega), \ \omega_2 = F_2 (F_1 (\omega))$ and $\omega_3 = F_3 (F_2 (F_1 (\omega)))$.

(b) Compute the area enclosed by the curve $\omega_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function $F_1$:

Let $w={z-1\over z+1}$, then $$w = {(z-1)\overline{z} \over (z+1)\overline{z}}= {z\overline{z}-\overline{z} \over z\overline{z}+\overline{z}}={1-\overline{z} \over 1+\overline{z}} =\overline{\Big({1-z\over 1+z}\Big)} =-\overline{w} $$

So $w+\overline{w}=0$ and thus $Re(w) =0$ so $w$ is on imaginary line.

And vice versa, every imaginary number $ib$ can be writen in the form ${z-1\over z+1}$ for some $z$ with $|z|=1$, just solve the equation:

$$ {z-1\over z+1} = ib$$ and you get $$z={1+ib\over 1-ib}\Longrightarrow |z| ={|1+ib|\over |1-ib|}=1 $$

Conclusion: $F_1$ maps $\omega$ to imaginary line $I$.

Comment: Following your idea, here's what I did. (Used different symbols to avoid confusion). Let z ∈ ω, and similarly let z1 ∈ ω1, z2 ∈ ω2, z3 ∈ ω3. 

z1 = F1(z), and we see that z1 is on the imaginary line, and further computation shows that |z1| = 1 ⇒ z1 = i. 

Therefore, z2 = F2(z1) = z1^2 = -1. 

And hence, z3 = F3(z2) = 1 + (-1)/1-(-1) = 0

And since z1 was an arbitrary points of ω1. F1 actually maps ω to i.

Comment: I don't understand why is $z_1$ just i?

Comment: Well, we got |z1|=1, and z1 is imaginary, won't z1 be i or -i?

Comment: $z_1$ is imaginary but $|z_1|$ is not necessarily  $1$.

Comment: Oh, damn! Yes, I made a very silly error while calculating the absolute value. My apologies. Can you explain me the significance of the "vice versa" in the solution of F1?

Comment: When you want to prove that to sets are equal, say $A=B$ then you must first prove that $A$ is subset of $B$ and then that $B$ is also a subset of $A$.

Comment: Ah, right! I completely forgot that we were talking about sets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Function $F_2$ takes each $ib$ to $-b^2$ so $F_2$ takes $I$ to negative real line with $0$ included.

Function $F_3$ is now actually just real function. It range is $(-1,1]$, since it domain is $(-\infty, 0]$.